# Azure AD B2C Post Sign In Information Collection

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am putting together a PoC to show Sign In followed by selection of a value from a dropdown box that is populated from an external API.

Standard Sign In is perfect and the example at https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/selectemail is great but I need to chain the 2, eg must successfully sign in first and then call the API to retrieve data for the user to select.

I know that this can be done with a 3rd part application between B2C and the end application but I am trying to avoid that. Can anyone point me to how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the user journey steps in the sample with the user journey you have. And concatenate the technical profiles in that sample into the policy file you are currently using (eg TrustframeworkExtensions).

Now you will have sign in -> rest api call -> display dynamic drop down box page.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It makes logical sense what you are saying but the practical is another story as I'm really new to the custom policy stuff. Are you able to point me to any documentation on how to do what you are saying?